# Custom helper functions in OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

Trying to create a custom PHP function within opencart. Basically I need to know if we are viewing the cart or checkout pages. I understand the simplest way to accomplish this is by accessing the route request param. I want to create a re-usable function however that is available site wide.

Is this possible? Where would it go?

The function looks something like this:

```
function isCheckout() {

    $route = $this->request->get['route'];

    //is cart?
    if($route == 'checkout/cart')
        return 'cart';

    $parts = explode('/', $route);

    if($parts[0] == 'checkout')
        return 'checkout';

    return false;

}
```

Comment: what is the problem .... first try this

Comment: Where do I put that? I don't know much about OpenCart. I have found that adding it to catalog/controller/common/header.php as a new function works fine, but will this be overwritten in an upgrade?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put your helper file inside a helper folder inside a system directory

`system/helper/myhelper.php`

and include it to

`system/startup.php` file

like this

`require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'helper/myhelper.php');`

and you are done.

Answer (score 4):

Put the function in a file eg. myhelper.php and save this to ../system/library/

Then add

```
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/myhelper.php');
```

to ../system/startup.php

Comment: And this will not be effected in an update? This would be considered the documented method? Thanks for the help.

Comment: why not put the helper files in `helper` folder rather than `library` folder

Answer (score 3):

The correct and recommended way of doing this is using the OpenCart's built-in loader:

```
$this->load->helper('helper_name');
```

The helper is located in the directory **system/helper.** You don't need to append the php suffix when you load it, as OpenCart's loader engine appends it automatically.

And then, because the helper is not a class you use the functions directly without the **$this.**
For example:

```
$this->load->helper('general');

token();
```

And the result will be a 32-character token. The **token()** function is located in the **general** helper in the **system/helper** directory.

This is an example of the **general** helper:

```
<?php
function token($length = 32) {
    // Create token to login with
    $string = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

    $token = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $token .= $string[mt_rand(0, strlen($string) - 1)];
    }   

    return $token;
}
```