# How to create global function in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to create simple function that can be executed on **any page**.

```
function something() {
    $string = 'Hello World'; 
    return $string;
}
```

Let's say I'm in the category page, I would just call `$a = something();` and it would return my value

Platform : OpenCart

*P.S. I'm still studying MVC architecture*

Comment: Learning how to define a function and learning MVC design pattern is approximately 3 years apart. This question has absolutely nothing to do with MVC (removed the tag).

Comment: Possible duplicate and answer can be found here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052307/custom-helper-functions-in-opencart

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are wanting to understand and learn about the MVC system, the correct way to go about this would be to create your own helper file and put it in `/system/helper/` and then add the helper to `system/startup.php`. Take a look at how the `json.php` / `utf8.php` are done in these as a guide

Comment: thank.. work like a charm...more easy to create new function and can call this function anywhere .. :D

Answer (score 3):

Create a new file to system/library/yourclassname.php with same code.

Also please add a class name to your function as below:

```
class yourclassname {

  function something() {
    $string = 'Hello World'; 
    return $string;
  }
}
```

And add it to your index.php file as below;

```
$registry->set('yourclassname', new yourclassname($registry));
```

Finally add it to your startup.php file as below:

```
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/yourclassname.php');
```

You can use it anywhere with $this->yourclassname->something();

Thats All..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function in any opencart library (system/library/)

As example in  system/library/document.php

```
    function something() {
    $string = 'Hello World'; 
    return $string;
}
```

And use anywhere in openсart  as

```
$something=$this->document->something();
```

P/s code in  header.tpl will not work in ajax or direct request

Comment: Good point on the AJAX request. While yes it's possible to create methods in a library class, this would only be advisable if the method related to that class. Otherwise, it's more of a "hack" than an actual practice that should be encouraged

Comment: All depends on the final target. I would have used MVC model  and $this->load->model('xxx/xxx'); $this->model_xxx_xxx->something();

Comment: Yes it does depend on the target, but ultimately if your function doesn't relate to the library file you edit it shouldn't be in there at all. Also, based on the OP wanting a simple function not an object method, it makes more sense to simply use a helper file (as OpenCart does itself) and include that in the `system/startup.php` file to maintain consistency

Answer (score 0):

Matricore's answer worked perfectly for me, but I also had to construct the new class with the config and db available.

Code below:

```
class yourclassname {

    public function __construct($registry) {
        $this->config = $registry->get('config');
        $this->db = $registry->get('db');
    }

}
```

You can then run queries via $this->db->query("Your query here");